# angularjs http.post() not receiving response

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #a{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="username"><br>
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password"><br>
<button ng-click="login()">login</button>
<p id="a">
{{ resmsg }}<br>
<br></p>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app= angular.module('myapp',[]);
    app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope , $http, $templateCache) {
        $scope.resmsg ="";

        $scope.login = function()
        {
            $http({
            method: 'POST', 
            url:'http://localhost/ng/myphp.php',
             data:{username : $scope.username, password : $scope.password},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},  
            cache: $templateCache
        }).success(function(response) {
            $scope.resmsg = response;
        }).error(function(response){

        })
            $scope.resmsg = response;
        }


    })
</script>
</body>

</html>`


myphp.php

<? php

 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $username = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;
    if($username == "admin" && $password== "admin"){
        echo "1";
    }
    else {
        echo "0";
    }

?>
```

[image]

> I was trying to create a simple login form using angularjs, php i have
>   tried lot to send my form data to php file using http.post() method
>   in angular js but not getting any thing as a response and getting
>   errormsg (screenshot) , the error is like there is no function like
>   success 
>   help me to get rid from this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of angular are you using? `$http.success` was deprecated in angular 1.5 and removed in angular 1.6. You should use `$http.then`, like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST', 
    url:'http://localhost/ng/myphp.php',
    data:{username : $scope.username, password : $scope.password},
    cache: $templateCache
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.resmsg = response.data;
}).catch(function(response){
    var err = response.data;
    // process error
})
```

Next, you have an error in the opening php tag, there is an extra space (use `<?php` instead of `<? php`.

Also it looks like your server is not processing the file with PHP, it just returns the PHP code itself. Try to access the script directly and see if it returns the code or executes it. If it returns the code as string, there is an error in your web server configuration.

Comment: please have look at the screenshot of error note , it will help you to understand the problem exactly what i am facing

Comment: you're right, I forgot about the content type. it should be working fine when you omit the line (so the default content type will be used, which is `application/json` in case of a POST request).